# Audio Problems html5

Tags: css, html, audio

I have encountered a slight issue on the website I am building. The problem is that the audio plays fine on the home page just like I want it to but when I navigate to other pages on my website then go back to the homepage, there seems to be TWO audio files playing. Here is my code so far for having the background audio on the home page.

```
<audio autoplay>
  <source src="audio/sound.mp3" type = "audio/mpeg">
    Your browser doesn't support audio 
</audio>
```

Is it possible without the use of AJAX, or maybe even JavaScript to just make that audio restart on the home page with only one song playing instead of the same song playing twice? Any help or advice is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: you have to post you actual code, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: this is the actual code I am using

Comment: if you noticed it play twice, should be something else other then that, how you are loading pages on your site? ajax call?

Comment: I am using ruby rails. Each link has it's own functionality and it's weird because that's the only file (the home file) which has audio code in it.

Comment: Are you using turbolinks by any chance?

Comment: I do though, have the turbolink gem installed @will

Comment: That would explain why it's playing twice, I think! I'll add a javascript solution below.

Comment: Would uninstalling the turbolink gem be a good idea then?

Comment: @Aaron: see my answer for a full demo of what you asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot! It just stops, resets, and plays the audio when you land on the page. Make sure to give the audio file a corresponding ID.

```
   var mySong = document.getElementById("mySong");
   mySong.pause();
   mySong.currentTime = 0;
   mySong.play();
```

Comment: Sure thing! I'd just open your inspector and make sure there aren't any duplicates of the audio player you added the ID to, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

> - **full working demo** http://so.devilmaycode.it/audio-problems-html5/

you may want to use [Media Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) to catch your [audio position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/buffering_seeking_time_ranges) offset, store it somewhere, maybe using `cookies` and then start from that position when navigating the site, after the page has finished to load.

in the demo i have simulated a page load by using a simple `setTimeout()`, you can check that music stop and then restart without loosing current position.

hope this help. ([plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zyIUOyBTDmTzbgoMcYcS?p=preview))